# Equal distance for two objects not adjacent to each other

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am new to Illustartor and was creating a border. I was wondering if there is an easy to way to exactly create equal distance between two non-adjacent objects. For example, the two white spaces highlighted in yellow:

[image]

I can 'eye' the distance to make them look like they are equal, but is there a way to do this accurately?

Thanks!

Comment: ermm... equidistant from what? Two parallel lines are *always* going to be equidistant from each other.

Answer (score 2):

I may be lazy, but I usually just draw a rectangle with the same width as the desired gap, position copies of it in the gaps and align the objects with those copies. Then, I delete the copies.

Don't forget to keep the original rectangle somewhere off-canvas or hidden, for later reuse.

Comment: …or you can use a line with the specific width. Often times I will leave the line in place, rather than remove it, which is fine as long as you don't need the background to show through.

Comment: @ispaany I find a rectangle works better, for it allows me to use the smart guides to align precisely. A line needs to be expanded to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Two objects can't be distributed to equalize space. There's just not enough data to create any kind of equidistant calculation. *More* than two objects can be distributed to equalize space between them my using the **Distribute spacing** buttons on the **Align Panel**

The *only way* two objects would *not* have an equal distance between them is if one or both of the objects were at an angle in relation to each other. Rotating objects to perfect vertical or horizontal, or making the angles of the two object identical, would inherently create an equal space between two objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question could be answered if you group them and center them to the center shapes. If you need the center shapes to stay, select the lines, center shape, and click the center again and hit center.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can distribute objects in equal distance. Check out the [illusrator help](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/moving-aligning-distributing-objects.html) page that explains this in detail.

Snippet from the help page:

> Move multiple objects at once Select one or more objects.
>
> Choose Object > Transform > Transform Each.
>
> Set the distance you want to move the selected objects in the Move
>   section of the dialog box.
>
> Do one of the following:
>
> To move the objects by the specified amounts, click OK.
>
> To move the objects randomly, but no more than the specified amounts,
>   select the Random option. For example, if you draw a brick wall and
>   want the bricks to appear slightly offset from each other instead of
>   perfectly aligned, you could select the Random option. Then click OK.